# Problems starting a WebSphere 9.0 app on developer's PC

Tags: debugging, ssl, websphere

We have a remote PC loaded with WebSphere 9.0 and we're trying to run an app that works in production, but we need to debug some things on the remote PC using Eclipse. We seem to have some kind of SSL problem with the app on the remote PC. We try to log in to the app, and get errors when it tries to get jquery - status 500. The jquery file it wants is definitely in the project.
[image]
Here is part of the logfile:

```
[1/18/23 12:02:30:787 EST] 000000fc webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception:
[1/18/23 12:02:30:721 EST] 000000fc SystemErr     R [/directory] - com.ait.security.servlets.ErrorS.displayError: (SSO artifact)
Request URI: GET /directory/lib/jquery-1.12.4.min.js
Remote addr: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
Remote user: snagamalli
Referer: https://localhost:9443/directory/loginForm
Status code: 500
Status code: 500
Servlet name: Static File wrapper
Servlet error message: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.ClosedConnectionException: OutputStream encountered error during write
Parameters:
    _=1673975347000

javax.servlet.ServletException: com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.ClosedConnectionException: OutputStream encountered error during write
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.FileServletWrapper.service(FileServletWrapper.java:751)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.FileServletWrapper.handleRequest(FileServletWrapper.java:543)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.StaticFileServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(StaticFileServletWrapperImpl.java:176)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:780)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.ait.security.filters.SecurityCheckFilter.doFilter(SecurityCheckFilter.java:99)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ait.security.filters.PerformanceFilter.doFilter(PerformanceFilter.java:78)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ait.web.html.ImproveCachingFilter.doFilter(ImproveCachingFilter.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:979)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1119)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4219)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.handleRequest(WebAppImpl.java:2210)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1030)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
Caused by: com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.ClosedConnectionException: OutputStream encountered error during write
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferOutputStream.write(WCCByteBufferOutputStream.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTOutputStream.write(SRTOutputStream.java:106)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.writeOut(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:837)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.writeThis(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:529)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.write(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:438)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.FileServletWrapper.writeByBytes(FileServletWrapper.java:1076)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.FileServletWrapper._writeResponseToClient(FileServletWrapper.java:1035)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.FileServletWrapper.writeResponseToClient(FileServletWrapper.java:944)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.FileServletWrapper.service(FileServletWrapper.java:723)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Fail to wrap application data
    at com.ibm.jsse2.g.a(g.java:26)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:102)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:22)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bg.a(bg.java:308)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bg.wrap(bg.java:289)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:37)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLWriteServiceContext.encryptMessage(SSLWriteServiceContext.java:619)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLWriteServiceContext.encryptAndWriteAsync(SSLWriteServiceContext.java:400)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLWriteServiceContext.write(SSLWriteServiceContext.java:331)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLWriteServiceContext.write(SSLWriteServiceContext.java:177)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.asynchWrite(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:2523)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.sendOutgoing(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:2307)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundServiceContextImpl.sendResponseBody(HttpInboundServiceContextImpl.java:902)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.writeBufferAsynch(WCChannelLink.java:744)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.writeBufferResponse(WCChannelLink.java:718)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.writeBuffer(WCChannelLink.java:655)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferOutputStream.flushWriteBuffer(WCCByteBufferOutputStream.java:723)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferOutputStream.checkWriteArray(WCCByteBufferOutputStream.java:631)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferOutputStream.write(WCCByteBufferOutputStream.java:197)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: Could not determine buffer size
    at javax.crypto.CipherSpi.a(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.n$o$a.a(n$o$a.java:61)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.d.e(d.java:14)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.d.a(d.java:123)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.e.a(e.java:162)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.e.a(e.java:130)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bg.c(bg.java:126)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bg.b(bg.java:274)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bg.a(bg.java:239)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cipher has not been initialized
    at com.ibm.crypto.plus.provider.ChaCha20Poly1305Cipher.a(ChaCha20Poly1305Cipher.java:144)
    at com.ibm.crypto.plus.provider.ChaCha20Poly1305Cipher.engineDoFinal(ChaCha20Poly1305Cipher.java:187)
    ... 69 more
```

Apps that don't use SSL seem to work. We checked the default certificates in the WebSphere administrative console, but they seem to be ok - not expired.

I've installed WebSphere on developer's PCs many times, so don't think I missed anything, but that's certainly possible. Googling the various error messages doesn't seem to give us anything helpful, but the error messages seem explicit enough that they should lead us to the problem:

OutputStream encountered error during write...
Fail to wrap application data...
Could not determine buffer size...
Cipher has not been initialized...

Does anyone have any ideas about what may be wrong?

Comment: What's the full websphere and java versions?  Likely goes away with a java update.

Comment: WebSphere is 9.0.5.6. Java version is IBM's "1.8.0_321"

Comment: You want to get it to 1.8.0_351 (or the other output '...build 8.0.7.20') or higher.

Comment: Updated to 1.8.0_351 (Eclipse starts using that version, eclipse.ini has: -vm
C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/1.8.0_351/bin/javaw.exe). Still seeing the same errors. Tried it with a different app and also see the same errors.

Comment: App seems to work on another PC running an older version of IBM's java - 1.8.0_241. Installing that on the problem PC....